# Did Ki Mendrossen from "Sarek" study the teachings of Surak?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, vulcan

In the *TNG* episode "[Sarek](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sarek_(episode))", Ambassador Sarek arrives on the Enterprise-D with a small entourage that includes a Terran male named Ki Mendrossen, who introduces himself to Picard and Riker as Sarek's Chief of Staff.

**Is Mr. Mendrossen a human who has studied the teachings of Surak?**  Mendrossen is quite rigid for a human and he betrays no emotion (or very little emotion) in his dealings with Sarek's group and with the Enterprise crew.  Furthermore, he wears a Vulcan ceremonial sash and a Vulcan-style tunic / robe.  Perhaps these features are simply part of the procedure one must follow when working amongst Sarek's staff, regardless of his or her own culture.  Also, they might simply be the result of working on Vulcan for many years.

Still, I am curious about humans who have studied Vulcan teachings and abide by their way of life (in-universe).  Is there further evidence that Mendrossen is one such person?

There exists a Memory Alpha article regarding Mendrossen, but it contains little information other than what is in the episode itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the main TV and Film canon, Ki Mendrossen only appears in the one episode, TNG : Sarek.

Based on the fact that an identical outfit (in reality, the same outfit) was worn by a visiting Vulcan Archaeologist in TNG : QPid, we can assume that the robe is indeed ceremonial, and presumably worn for special occasions such as meeting foreign dignitaries.

History doesn't record whether he's an adherent of Vulcan philosophy or merely employed as a member of Sarek's staff.

---

Within the EU, rather more is known about Ki Aloysius Mendrossen. He appears briefly in [TNG: Federation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_%28novel%29). Riker notes that his initial response suggests a Vulcan-like coolness.

> “What will happen to him then?” Riker asked.
>
> **Mendrossen, though human, answered with Vulcan control**.
>
> “The effects of Bendii Syndrome are irreversible.” Then, in an
>   afterthought that belied his emotions, he added hopefully, “Medical
>   research is always continuing.” There was nothing more to be said.

In [TNG : Avenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avenger_%28Star_Trek%29) (By William Shatner) we learn rather more about Mendrossen, including that he is indeed an adherent of the teachings of Surak:

> Spock cocked his head, intrigued, as he recognized the figure. Ki
>   Mendrossen. The diplomat who had served as his father’s chief of staff
>   in the final years of Sarek’s career. He was an officious human,
>   totally devoted to Sarek’s well-being, and possessed of an almost
>   Vulcanlike capacity to focus on details. Though Sarek had never
>   commented upon Mendrossen’s abilities, the fact that the man had
>   served so long was testament enough to his competence.

...

> Mendrossen bowed his head in a human expression of shame. He did it
>   awkwardly, as if his years on Vulcan had made him lose touch with his
>   own human heritage.
>
> “**For all that I believed I followed in the path of Surak**, my logic
>   was uncertain and I do regret my actions.”

Comment: "*Based on the fact that an identical outfit (in reality, the same outfit) was worn by a visiting Vulcan Archaeologist in TNG : QPid*" ... we could also assume this outfit was worn on both sets due to a cheap wardrobe department.

Comment: @paulster2 - Hence the reason why I've attempted to distinguish an 'in-universe' explanation :-))

Comment: Tongue-in cheek, Richard ...

Comment: @paulster - O I C...

Comment: @Richard : Thanks for the detail.  Is it really "Benalii" in *TNG: Federation*?  In the episode and in Memory Alpha, it is "Bendii".

Comment: @Praxis - That appears to be a transcription error in my OCR software. An a and an l together (αƖ) look a bit like a d

Answer (score 1):

Given how readily Mendrossen lied about Sarek's condition, I'd say he was not a strict follower of Surak.  Sarek likely had him on staff partialy because it was logical to have a staffer who could easily lie for the sake diplomacy when needed.